# Spring-Scala Bootstrapping

Tags: spring, scala

I currently have a Java/Spring application that is primarily configured via XML. The plan is to slowly migrate the application to Scala. I felt an easy first step would be to replace the XML configuration with a Scala configuration classes.

I have looked over [spring-scala](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-scala) and was going to try it out, however, I am running into issues figuring out how to bootstrap the classes extending `FunctionalConfiguration`.

The application currently uses `application.xml` loaded from `web.xml` to start the bootstrapping process via a component-scan. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to pick up the Scala config classes.

Any suggestions on how to bootstrap a spring-scala configuration?

Best,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Spring-scala seems quite [dead](http://hub.darcs.net/psnively/spring-scala/changes). It's not necessary to use it in order to migrate to scala. Old-fashioned java config works pretty well with scala.

Moreover, currently you don't need web.xml and even external servlet container - you can use [spring-boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). It'll allow you to throw away all XMLs and some java configuration parts.

[Here's an example](http://dimafeng.com/2016/01/02/scala-spring/) of the approach with spring-boot & scala. I hope this helps.